# Visual diagram to document Lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, diagram

While developing Lightning components at some point I realized a demand of documenting them. Purpose of this is to help other developers and myself to easier understand the functionality implemented. But rather visual diagram instead of written documentation. For example lets say there is a table component and row. Row has some data, edit and delete buttons. Clicking these buttons fires an event that is handled by table component and modal is displayed. I want to describe this interaction with diagram. I am not expert in UML, just wondering if standard component diagram is suitable for this case, is it able to represent components nesting, event handlers and dynamic component creation. Or there is other type of diagram for this purpose? I am looking for a documented industry standard that perfectly suits this problem.